# how to undo jQuery's one() using on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that needs to be fired not more than once :

```
    $(".menuIco").one('click', function() {
        $(this).menuIcoClick($(this));
    });
```

...that leads to function :

```
$.fn.menuIcoClick = function(menuIco) {
     [...does some animations, not important...]
    }
```

However, after other event I would like that event to be able to fire up again. I'm trying to bind `menuIco`'s click event with `menuIcoClick` function again using `on()` :

```
.on('click', $('#analiza').menuIcoClick($('#analiza')));
```

in

```
$("#icoBack").click(function() {
        $('#analiza').animate({left: ($("#analiza").data("left")), top: ($("#analiza").data("top"))}, 0).on('click', $('#analiza').menuIcoClick($('#analiza')));
    });
```

but it doesn't work, `on()` method doesn't let me click (and fire up once-only event) on that element again, as I expected.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to pass the element as a parameter to your plugin as it will be available via the `this` keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195052/jquery-unbind-events-bound-with-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.off` inside your first function:

```
$(".menuIco").on('click', function() {
    $(this).menuIcoClick($(this));
    $(".menuIco").off('click'); // Here we disable the event, on the first execution
});
```

For do the event again you need to set it into a new function, attached to event that you want.

If this not work, please send us a jsfiddle showing up with more details your problem.

Comment: I'd like to, but [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjJXf/1/) somehow fails to work on a simple event. Anyway, the problem is that I can't `bind` (or turn `on()`) the function back. I have no idea why this doesn't work: `$(".menuIco").on('click', $(".menuIco").menuIcoClick());` while this works `$(".menuIco").on('click', function() { $(this).menuIcoClick(); });`

Comment: I see now what was the problem, I should write `$(".menuIco").on('click', $(".menuIco").menuIcoClick);`, not `(...).menuIcoClick());`.

Comment: @OverdrivenFall I've make an fiddle showing what I want to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/KjJXf/2/ I've used another sintax for the `.on`, see if it helps you.