# Alert does not appear for links inserted by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a large codebase, and I'm trying to write some JQuery so that whenever the user clicks on a link (i.e. the `a` tag), there's an alert. This is what I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert("hey ho!"); 
    $("a").click(function(event){ 
        alert("Hello!"); 
    }); 
});
```

The "hey ho!" alert shows up, so JQuery is working. Now, the links in this file are **not** actually in the HTML code, but rather they are inserted by some other JavaScript. I can print them out as DOM elements and see them on my console:

```
<a style="..." href="...">
```

They are internal links, and when I click on them, they jump to the correct place. However, there is no alert. What might be the problem? How could I debug this?

Comment: The collection of nodes obtained through `$("a")` is non-live and so will not be updated if more nodes are added.

Comment: Whatever js is inserting the links is running after you are trying to attach the click listener; @dystroy's answer will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation so that the new elements also can receive the event :

```
$(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    alert("Hello!"); 
});
```

Comment: Mostly, yes (not inside, though). But `live` has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle to demonstrate it this week, answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592258/2394172):

http://jsfiddle.net/KjJXf/2/

This demonstrate the use of `.on` and `.off`.

By doing the `.on`, your event get "live" in the page, including for the new HTML that can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may bind click event when you insert a link, put the following code exactly after the code that is inserting link.

```
$('a').unbind('click'); // to unbind from all previous a tags

/// bind to all again
$('a').on('click',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

If you are using jQuery version previous than 1.9 then you can use:

```
/// bind to all again
    $('a').live('click',function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
```