# unbind event handler and event then turn them back on

Tags: jquery

I am trying to unbind then bind the `one` handler and `mousemove` event when the user changes pages in pagination for this table.

The problem I am having is that when the user switches pages the `one` handler does not trigger again for obvious reasons since it is still being applied even when the user switches pages. I am using `one` apposed to `on` for performance reasons.

I am able to detect the page change with `$table.on('page-change.bs.table', function () {` which is firing, but the `unbind` and `bind` is not resetting the `one` handler again so it fires again for that page.

Basically I need the `one` to fire once for every page and not once overall.

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 2500,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 200,
    pageList: [200, 400, 1000, 2000],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'ID',
        title: 'ID',
        align: 'center',
        visible: false
    }]
});



$('#table-javascript').one('mousemove', function() {
...
});
$table.on('page-change.bs.table', function () {
    $('#table-javascript').unbind('one', function() {
        $(this).bind('one');    
    });
});
```

Comment: .unbind('mousemove');

Comment: but what about the `one` handler, I need it to fire again once when the page changes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195052/jquery-unbind-events-bound-with-one