# Choose only the first button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm trying to do that only one can happen, if you click yes or no. As it is now if you click "no" in the first time and "yes" in the second time, it will execute it twice .

```
function confirm() { 
    $("#no").one("click", function(){ 
       return false;
    });
}

$("#yes").one("click", function () {
    //do something
});
```

thanks for help

Comment: Can you paste your complete code or create a jsfiddle for your scenario

Comment: You are setting 2 event handlers. You either need to to just set 1 event handler `$('.confirm-button').one("click", function() { ... } ` that handles both buttons (checks for a 'yes'/'no' values and responds appropriately), or you need to unbind the 'other' event handler when either 'yes' or 'no' is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Both events are attached at document.ready I assume, which means they will remain active indefinitely unless you specify otherwise.

The following approach is fairly basic, just set a variable 'hasClicked' to false. And as soon as either one of them is clicked, set 'hasClicked' to true. Each button has an if-structure that only executes the code IF 'hasClicked' is false.

Try the following:

```
var hasClicked = false;
function confirm(){

    $("#no").one("click", function(){
        if (!hasClicked){
            hasClicked = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#yes").one("click", function () {
        if (!hasClicked) {
            hasClicked = true;
            //do something
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can't unbind an event binded with `one()` [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195052/jquery-unbind-events-bound-with-one)

So you'll have to work around like this:

```
function confirm() { 
    $("#no").bind("click", function(){ 
      $(this).unbind();    // prevent other click events
      $("#yes").unbind("click");  // prevent yes click event
      // Do your stuff
    });
}

$("#yes").bind("click", function () {
  $(this).unbind();
  $("#no").unbind("click");
  // Do your stuff
});
```

Comment: i won't unbind something, it is ong code but this is the only thing that does not work properly

Comment: You can't change the code you are working on ?

Another solution is to use a boolean to handle if the action still needs to be done or not, but you answered that @Tom-Nijs 's proposition doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Assign your buttons a class called `confirmation`. Set a event handler based on class. Read the value of the button to decide what you want to do.

```
     $(".confirmation").one("click", function(){
      if($(this).val() === 'yes'){
        //do something
       }else{
         return false;
       }
     }
```